# micrsosoft bot framework with deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, botframework

I would like to create a similar bot like Microsoft's Tay . I've been searching online for 2 days on how to create a similar bot but I am unable to find. I am searching for deep learning with bot framework but no results.

Can someone tell me the starting point for my study or how to do a bot such as Tay?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Microsoft Bot Framework, your bot is just a normal service, so you can use any technology / library / API. I'd recommend checking out the Microsoft Cognitive Services APIs (www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services), they allow you to use their models used in Bing and Cortana; might be a good starting point.